# Cannot get Sent or Drafts folder with JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I'm using **JavaMail** to get a list of ALL the folders in an **IMAPStore**:

```
store.getDefaultFolder().list("*")
```

This usually works fine with accounts at Gmail, Yahoo etc. However, for some IMAP providers the list method returns only one folder, namely the inbox. Yet, when using the same account via Thunderbird I can also access the account's Sent and Drafts folders. Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong in getting the folders?

---

PS: Also directly checking for folders like "Sent", "Sent items","Drafts" etc. via

```
store.getFolder(foldername).exists()
```

always returns false.

---

**Supplement**: These are the properties I use to create the Session (javax.mail.Session) which I get the store from:

```
props.put("mail.store.protocol","imaps");
props.put("mail.imaps.host","imap.testhost.com");
props.put("mail.imaps.port","993");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth","true");
props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust","*");
props.put("mail.imaps.partialfetch","false");
```

Comment: Thunderbird is maybe creating "local" folders?  And the folders don't actually exist?  Or Thunderbird creates them when it connects for the first time.

Comment: @Max: As far as I can tell from the folders' options in Thunderbird, the Sent and Drafts folders do not seem to differ from the Inbox folder. Also, when accessing the account via the provider's web interface, the Sent and Drafts folders are available. That's why I think that the folders are probably there (in the IMAP store) but I seem to be doing something wrong in retrieving them.

Comment: Are you accessing via POP3 or IMAP?  Can you show your connection code?  POP does not support folders.

Comment: The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might provide some clues, but if you're using IMAP it sounds like the server isn't telling you about the folders.

Comment: @Max: Yes, it is IMAP. To connect to the store I simply call **store.connect()**. I will add the details of the properties object for the Session to the question.